# Status of a conjectural definition of H. Nakajima

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, rt.representation-theory

In his paper '$t$-analogue of $q$-characters of finite dimensional representations of quantum affine algebras' - http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0009231 - H. Nakajima states a conjectural definition of the $t$-analogue of the $q$-character of a standard module $M_{P}$ (with weight $P$) of a quantum affine algebra at level $0$ - this appears as Conjecture 3.1.1 on p. 5 of the arXived preprint above. In summary, Nakajima conjectures that the $q,t$'-character  of a standard module $M_{p}$ can be determined using certain filtrations on individual weight spaces.

I was hoping that someone can let me know of the status of this conjecture - is it true that we can describe the '$q,t$'-character as conjectured?

I imagine that this has been resolved since the paper is a bit more mature now. If this is the case, can someone point me in the direction of a resolution?

If this conjecture has not been resolved, does anyone know of any progress towards its resolution/any problems that have arisen in resolving this conjecture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2321.

Comment: Thanks for your response and reference; I will take a look! Cheers, George

Answer (score 1):

The following paper might help get you up to date, by working through its references:

*Yoshiyuki Kimura, Fan Qin.  Graded quiver varieties, quantum cluster algebras and dual canonical basis.*

http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2066

It contains some material on $q,t$-characters and twisted versions of these, in relation to some problems in the theory of quantum cluster algebras.

In particular it references

*David Hernandez. Algebraic approach to q,t-characters.
Advances in Mathematics 187 (2004), no. 1, 1–52.*

which I imagine (though I've not read it) should be pretty close to what you want.